# JS: easy way to convert string "foo[bar]" into code obj.foo.bar?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an variable `obj` defined as follows:

```
{user: {username: "AzureDiamond", password: "hunter2"}}
```

I have a string `str` that might be defined as any of the following strings:

- "user"
- "user[username]"
- "user[password]"
- "fake"

Is there a relatively easy way for me in JS (specifically node.js) to essentially/dynamically perform the following?

- when `str == "user"`, return `{username: "AzureDiamon", password: "hunter2"}`
- when `str == "user[username]"`, return "AzureDiamond"
- when `str == "user[password]"`, return "hunter2"
- when `str == "fake"`, return `null`

**Edit:** This question is more to find out if there's anything easier or build into JS/node.js that I can use other than regex matches.

Comment: Are you able to change this so instead of using the bracket syntax you use the dot syntax? Ex: user.password instead of user[password]. That would make it a little easier to manage.

Comment: For the JS, yes.  For the strings, no.  The reason is that this has to do with query string params.

Comment: Why is the syntax for the retrieving a first level different than other levels? if it's for simplicity, why not use dot syntax?

Comment: @JuanMendes (Copying/pasting this from someone who asked below.)  The format user[username] is a common idiom in query params. See Ruby on Rails and Express.js as examples, where they are automatically converted to Hashes and Objects, respectively. Rails will not convert user.username into a Hash, and node.js will not convert user.username into an Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

If you are sure the syntax of `str` is correct, the function could look like this:

```js
function get_by_path(source, path){
    var path_elements = path.split(']').join('').split('[');
    for (var i=0; i < path_elements.length; i++){
        source = source[path_elements[i]];
        if (typeof source === 'undefined'){
            return null;
        }
    };
    return source;
};
```

### Test

This is how it behaves:

```
var data = {'user': {
    'username': "AzureDiamond", 'password': "hunter2",
    'details': {'address': {'street': "Happiness Street"}}
}};

get_by_path(data, 'user');                           // gives user object
get_by_path(data, 'user[username]');                 // gives "hunter2"
get_by_path(data, 'user[password]');                 // gives "AzureDiamond"
get_by_path(data, 'fake');                           // gives null
get_by_path(data, 'user[details][address][street]'); // gives "Happiness Street"
```

### Explanation

The script does not use regular expression, nor dangerous `eval()` calls, only assumes your "*path*" will start with one word without brackets and every next part (if any) will be word enclosed in square brackets. If some path will not be found within the traversed object, `null` will be returned. If it will be found, it will be returned (regardless of whether it will be some complex object, string, `null`, boolean or anything else).

Script begins with parsing your path. It does that by removing closing square brackets ("`]`") and splitting resulting string by opening square brackets ("`[`"). The process looks like this:

```
"user"                  -> "user"                -> ["user"]
"user[username]"        -> "user[username"       -> ["user", "username"]
"user[password]"        -> "user[password"       -> ["user", "password"]
"user[address][street]" -> "user[address[street" -> ["user", "address", "street"]
"fake"                  -> "fake"                -> ["fake"]
```

So, as you see, at the end you have an array of path elements. These are evaluated one by one. If at any level appropriate step cannot be made deeper into the structure of the data argument, then `null` is returned. Otherwise the last accessed element is returned.

### Proof

Proof that it works is here: http://jsfiddle.net/EJCgE/2/

**EDIT**: There was some issue with more complex paths (when there were more than two levels), resulting from how string's `replace()` method works. I have updated my code to not include jQuery and to fix that issue.

**EDIT2**: I have updated the script to remove redundant lines and one redundant variable.

Comment: Nice, but doesn't work with deeper structures like `{user: {c: {a:3}}}` `get_by_path(data, 'user[c][a]')`  http://jsfiddle.net/6ULMK/1/ Could be good enough for OP though

Comment: @JuanMendes: You are right, it does not. Strangely, this is because `.replace(']','')` does not actually replace every "`]`" occurence, only one: http://jsfiddle.net/5gfAs/

Comment: @JuanMendes: I fixed that issue (see updated answer and http://jsfiddle.net/EJCgE/1/), so you can now use it for complex cases. I have also removed jQuery's dependency.

Comment: @Tadeck `.replace(/\]/g, "").split("[")` should do the trick and be more efficent

Comment: @JuanMendes: It is arguable, as the tests have shown that sometimes regular expression is more efficient, sometimes splitting is (http://jsperf.com/parsing-get-params-names). The difference is really rather insignificant and varies across browsers. Eg. in Chrome splitting instead of regexp is fastest for two and four levels, while regular expression seems to be always faster for one level (when there is actually no bracket to be replaced). Your proposal wins significantly on some slow Safari version in 50% cases (other 50% cases have insignificant differences).

Answer (score 2):

This is taken directly from the EXTJS3 source code but I've used it many times to do similar things.

```
createAccessor : function(){
    var re = /[\[\.]/;
    return function(expr) {
        if(Ext.isEmpty(expr)){
            return Ext.emptyFn;
        }
        if(Ext.isFunction(expr)){
            return expr;
        }
        var i = String(expr).search(re);
        if(i >= 0){
            return new Function('obj', 'return obj' + (i > 0 ? '.' : '') + expr);
        }
        return function(obj){
            return obj[expr];
        };

    };
}(),
```

You would use this like so:

```
var accessor = createAccessor(str);
var data = accessor(object);
```

Comment: This actually ends up using eval... (through the `Function` constructor)

Comment: Your right that it does use eval but first it checks it through a regex for sanity.

Comment: Interesting approach.  I would need to dig into the issues with using `new Function` and how that pertains to `eval`.  One thing worth noting is that I would still need to change my string from "user[username]" to "user['username']", for example.

Comment: @MattHuggins I don't think `user[username]` is a good string to pass in, it's not really how things work, it would be your own new standard, how about `user.username` ?

Comment: The code I pasted above works for both user.username and user["username"] but not user[username]

Comment: @MattHuggins That's because `user[username]` means get a property whose name is stored in the variable username, part of the reason why I think this is a bad idea, it's too close to how JS works, but different, gonna confuse people. Use dot notation and be done with it

Comment: The format `user[username]` is a common idiom in query params.  See Ruby on Rails and Express.js as examples, where they are automatically converted to Hashes and Objects, respectively.  Rails will not convert `user.username` into a Hash, and node.js will not convert `user.username` into an Object.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `eval` function.  It takes a string, and executes that string as if it were javascript code.  For example:

```
var data = {user: {username: "AzureDiamond", password: "hunter2"}};
var str = "user[\"password\"]";
console.log( eval("data." + str) );
// Prints "hunter2"
```

You have to be VERY careful with this though, because depending on where that `str` comes from, people could essentially run code on your server remotely.  Use a regex to validate the string before execution, to make sure that people can't send you sneaky information and hack your server to bits.

EDIT: Note that you also have to quote `password` so that it's treated as a string when executed, not a variable.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have mentioned that I know about eval and am trying to avoid it for security reasons. :)  Given that, this example still would not work, as "password" would need to be quoted within the brackets for it to eval properly.

Comment: Okay, now it would work with your edit, but your answer would still require some kind of regex or something to find the brackets.

Comment: I figured that out soon after posting haha, and yes if you're going to use eval you can't get around the regex really.  I can give a suggestion as to what I would use, but I'm also not really sure how general this procedure has to be.